# Xcode 8.1 beta storyboard not dynamic

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Views show as rectangular rather than the square dynamic way that takes into account multiple devices. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've taken a new approach to this. It's still "dynamic" and it still "takes into account multiple devices", but the interface is different — and, I think, clearer.

There is now a View As button at the lower left. Click it, and you'll see every possible size and orientation your interface can assume. Click an interface size-and-orientation to see what your interface looks like with it.

[image]

As to "why", you might want to watch the WWDC 2016 video on this topic. I think they justify this change pretty well.